# Updating spring boot cache every 5 hours

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, netflix-feign

Requirement :
Update cache with some data every 5 hours

**Scheduler class**

```
@Component
public class SomeCacheDataUpdateScheduler{


    @Autowired
    DataFeignClient feignClient;

    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;


    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 2000)
    public void run()  {
        List<SomeObject> objList=feignClient.findAllData();


        objList.forEach(obj->cacheManager.getCache("cache-name").put(obj.getId(), obj));
    }

}
```

**Cache manager config class**

```
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig{

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("cache-name");
    }

}
```

Now, on debugging, I know that "feignClient.findAllData();" is returning the desired object. But somehow the cache is not getting populated. And when I fetch a specific value from the cached map using a valid key, It is returning null value.

```
SomeObject sObj=cacheManager.getCache("cache-name").get("203",SomeObject.class);
```

The above call is made after running the scheduler.

I'm absolutely new to spring boot's caching mechanism and any help regarding this issue and the best practices for caching will be much appreciated!

Comment: What is `store`?  Is `obj.getId()` a String?  Is the referenced `cacheManager` the same instance?

Comment: Ignore the store part, i have edited it to be obj. 'store' was the name of the object 'obj' in the original code, i wanted to make it generic.
obj.getId() is a string.

Comment: How do I ensure that cacheManager is in same instance?

Comment: The scheduler class injects `cacheManager` via @Autowired.  The class which contains the `SomeObject sObj=cacheManager.getCache("cache-name").get("203",SomeObject.class);` line must also inject the `cacheManager` so both classes are referring to the same instance.

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: It looks reasonable, assuming the cache does need to be loaded all at once and `cacheManager` is wired correctly.

Comment: I was able to make it work. I didn't put @EnableCaching annotation in the application startup class.
Thanks for the help!